# nothing is holding *thinks up* if you need something

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I received an email with:
"I just want to ensure that nothing is holding thinks up if you need something."
I know what he meant:"I just want to ensure that you're ready (or you can use what you need) if you need something."

But I can't explain the structure of the part "thinks up".

Nothing(Subject)
is holding (verb)
thinks up (this should be an objective. what was omitted here?)

Comment: I'd say it's simply a typo. Read: "I just want to ensure that nothing is holding things up if you need something."

Comment: It's probably a typo and is supposed to say, "I just want to ensure that nothing is holding things up if you need something." The idiom is "holding things up", meaning to cause a delay or a stoppage of progress.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo *(**thinks = things**)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to hold someone/thing up** (phrasal verb)

> 3. Delay or block the movement or progress of someone or something:
>
> *‘our return flight was held up for seven hours’*
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold-someone/thing-up

As others have noted, the expression as you transcribed it is in error. "thinks" should be "things".